# my dynamic ip is not syncing with cloudflare

Tags: networking, macos, dynamic-dns

I have tried to set up a domain using cloudflare:

[image]

it is meant to point to my ip address, but my ip changes very often. (It is not actually 79.79.237.46, that is an old ip that I set in cloudflare manually.)

So I tried to use ddclient to auto-update the cloudflare record, here's my `ddclient.conf` file:

```
##
## CloudFlare (www.cloudflare.com)
##
ssl=yes
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com
protocol=cloudflare,        \
zone=theonlygusti.tk,            \
server=www.cloudflare.com,  \
login=************@gmail.com,     \
password=**************************             \
theonlygusti.tk
```

Why doesn't the cloudflare record auto-update whenever my ip changes?

I basically followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/tehpeh/11274305) word-for-word in my setup.

Comment: Is `theonlygusti.tk` your actual domain?  It doesn't appear to actually be registered, so that may be your first problem.

Comment: @heavyd it isn't my actual domain

Answer (score 0):

lines ~= 30-66 are mechanisms to determine your current IP address. You may want to pull it from your router or you could ask an external host. Here's how to check by using dyndns.org

Edit this line to remove the `#`

```
# use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.org/
```

...to become:

```
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.org/
```

Comment: Seems to me that the 4th line in the question's `ddclient.conf` is already just that (without a trailing slash).